# Why can't I reach Redcliffe?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm in the first zone (Hinterlands) and my main quest is to go to Redcliffe, but I see a closed gate on the road to Redcliffe.

I read that I have to close the rift before the gate but this does not appear in my game.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redcliffe is accessible later on as part of the main storyline. Siding with the mages gives you access to Redcliffe, though I'm not sure if the same occurs should you side with the templars.

Comment: The mission to gain access to Redcliffe is not the mission where you side with the mages. It is needed to unlock the mission to side with the mages on the strategy table. But you can do all quests in Redcliffe and still side with the Templars.

Comment: Well, it's true. I had to go in Val Roeyaux on the war table before going in Redcliffe. Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 0):

I sided with the templars and only talked to Fiona in Val Royeaux. Once I did Champions of the Just, I talked to Crem and did a war table mission where the chargers infiltrate Redcliffe castle.

Now I entered without a problem - the door was open.